# PHP PDO error scope?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I've been searching and testing different approaches to fix my issue but I still can't find the damn solution. I'm new to PHP and i'm trying to teach myself working with PDO.

db.php:

```
<?php

$dsn = 'mysql:myHost=localhost;dbname=ewt';
$user= 'root';
$pass = '';

try {
    $pdo = new PDO($dsn, $user, $pass);
    $pdo ->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
}
catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo 'Connection failed: ' . $e->getMessage();
}
```

showCust.php

```
<?php

include_once('db.php');

try {


    $sql = "SELECT * FROM PERSOON";
    $result = $pdo->query($sql);
    while($row = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
        echo $row['VOORNAAM']. ' - '. $row['NAAM']. ' - '. $row['EMAIL']. ' - '. $row['ADRES']. '<br />';
    }
    $pdo = null;
}
catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

It works perfecty when I copy the db.php code in the showCust.php but I want to split the DB connection from every other file. I know it has to do something with the scope of $pdo but I just can't figure it out ...

The error i keep getting are:

> Notice: Undefined variable: pdo ... line 9
>
> Fatal error: Call to a member function query() on a non-object in ... line 9

I know the database does NOT have a pw. This is purely for test purposes.

Thanks in advance !

Comment: Kudos on starting with PDO! :) Is your connection successful? You are handling PDO object instantiation - I assume you are not getting a 'Connection failed' error? Unless... Are namespacing your code?

Comment: Thanks :D ! I actually started yesterday with mysqli but I've read PDO is much better so i'll convert that code later today to PDO! I'm not getting ANY errors when i combine both files in one. I get all the data from the database. But once I seperate them all hell breaks loose  :p

Comment: Don't get confused by PDO. An object is nothing but a good old PHP variable, no matter the class. Regular scope rules apply.

Comment: So it has to do with the try catch I guess?

Comment: @Daan in the db.php i assume ?

Comment: It's not `mysql:myHost` but `mysql:host=localhost` @user3511568 that's the problem.

Comment: @Fred-ii- I'll try that. It works though when I combine the files :(

Comment: Of course try/catch does not have its own scope! [Counter-example](http://3v4l.org/7JL1D)

Comment: I'm sure it will kick into gear @user3511568 When I used `myHost` in my PDO, it threw an error.

Comment: Changed it and I still get the same error. Also declared pdo outside the try catch still no luck !

Comment: Ok, well that's just part of the error. Let me see what I can do to work with what you posted. @user3511568

Comment: What happens if you remove the try catch block?

Comment: @Daan Removed the try catch on both files to test if it had to do with the scope. Still same error

Comment: Are the files in the same directory? :-

Comment: @Daan yes same directory. The thing is when i copy the db.php in addCust.php everything works ... With no scope issues or anything.

Comment: I tested your code with my credentials with no problem. @user3511568 Are you sure you're using those files and where are you using this, on your own localhost machine or a hosted service? Plus, using `mysql:host=localhost` as previously stated.

Comment: Yes everything works when I put the db config code inside the addCust.php file. I'm using XAMPP on my machine but I doubt it has anything to do with that since all my other stuff works. I forgot to mention i'm using include_once(addCust.php) in another PHP file. I doubt this is a correct way of coding in PHP but still learning :(

Comment: Does `addCust.php` also contain `include_once('db.php');`? Instead of doing `include_once` use `include` then @user3511568 Sounds like a scope issue at this point for sure.

Comment: I ment showCust :p Sorry. Kinda frustrated so I typed the wrong file

Comment: To be clear: There's customer.php where i'm using HTML5+bootstrap. I kinda wanted to seperate the actual script where the SELECT happens to  get all the customers so somewhere in customer.php i used include_once('showCust.php') (this is where the ACTUAL script happens ). 

I do realise this might not be the CORRECT way of coding in PHP but it's for a project so i'm trying to do my best

Comment: You should do **one** include that will or can include other files respectively. Using such a structure will allow you more freedom and less pain. @user3511568

Comment: I've tried everything so far to get rid of the $pdo error but nothing works so far haha! :p

Comment: possible duplicate of [Reference: What is variable scope, which variables are accessible from where and what are "undefined variable" errors?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16959576/reference-what-is-variable-scope-which-variables-are-accessible-from-where-and)

Comment: When i combine both files into one it does work. The thing is if $pdo exists in one try catch does it still exist in the other try catch ? This is a bit confusing haha

Comment: `try..catch` has zero influence on variable scope (see linked dupe above). The only real possibility in the code you show is that the file is not getting included, period. This may be because you've included it before elsewhere and are using `_once` (as Sense explains), or because the file does not exist and `include` is not killing the script because of it. Try `require` instead of `include_once`. The other possibility is that the example you show has nothing to do with your real code and there's an entirely different problem in your real code.

Comment: This is SO weird. After nearly 2 hours i deleted db.php created another file called pdoDb.php and now everything works with the 2 php files split. This is so .......... ***** !

Answer (score 1):

In essence, `*_once` functions in PHP are but a dirty trick. A crutch to help unsuspecting programmer to keep their code in order. But nothing goes for free.

This "once" behavior means you are running this function indeed **once.**
Means if you have included it *once* already, all the consequent calls will do... n o t h i n g.

Thus, if you used include_once for db.php earlier in the code and it was inside of a function, then $pdo variable remained local for that function, leaving global scope without $pdo variable. While when included next time, db.php weren't executed and thus you have got no $pdo at all.
However, it's just a speculation.

Other reasons could be various typos. Also make sure you are running exactly the same code you posted here. You'll be surprised by it's working flawlessly

Comment: That last sentence is almost, but not quite, meaningful English.

Comment: yes, I am bad with English. Thank you for your concern.

Comment: It's a good guess. The code we've seen cannot be the actual one. (We know that notices are enabled, though.)

Comment: I've always found your English pretty good, I just can't make out what you are trying to say. If $pdo was down in a function it was local to that function? I'm trying to parse what the "it" antecedents might be as I am sure there's something worth understanding there.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you did something like this:

```
$pdo = new PDO...;
function foo(){
    $pdo->query(...);
}
foo();
```

How about this?

```
$pdo = new PDO...;
function foo(PDO $pdo){
    $pdo->query(...);
}
foo($pdo);
```

The issue can also happen the other way round:

```
function foo(){
    $pdo = new PDO...;
}
foo();
$pdo->query(...);
```

You're probably posting a simplified example here, since the code you've shared should not trigger that notice. I suggest you actually try the simplified snippets outside your project.

---

You've just confirmed what I said about not being the actual code ;-)

> i'm using include_once(addCust.php) in another PHP file. I doubt this
>   is a correct way of coding in PHP but still learning

Make sure the first call to `include_once('addCust.php)'` does not happen before the first call to `include_once('db.php');` and they both take place in global scope. The notice can obviously also happen if you have this:

```
$pdo->query(...);
$pdo = new PDO...;
```

Comment: This time it wasn't me %)

Comment: Other times it was? :-O

Comment: Well, for every other answer here... `*blush*`

Comment: addCust doesn't exist. I typed it wrong due to frustration :p